# C-MPI Send created typedef struct with array of chars

Tags: c, struct, mpi

Hello I have a file containing that kind of data lines:

```
AsfAGHM5om  00000000000000000000000000000000  0000222200002222000022220000222200002222000000001111
```

I want to read this kind of data and send them over using C and MPI. So I've reached the following C code:

```
    #include <mpi.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stddef.h> // used for offsetof
    typedef struct tuple_str{
        char *key;
        char *index;
        char *value;
    } tuple;

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        // Initialize the MPI environment
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

        // Initialize file pointer
        FILE *fp = fopen("tuples","r");

        // define original structure that stores file and temp used by each process
        tuple A[10000],B[10000];
        // mpi structure name
        MPI_Datatype mpi_tuples_str;
        // number of structure members
        const int nitems = 3;
        // array of structure member sizes
        int blocklengths[3];
        blocklengths[0] = sizeof(A->key);
        blocklengths[1] = sizeof(A->index);
        blocklengths[2] = sizeof(A->value);
        // structure member types
        MPI_Datatype types[3] = {MPI_CHAR,MPI_CHAR,MPI_CHAR};
        // status
        MPI_Status status;
        // offset of structure members
        MPI_Aint offsets[3];
        offsets[0] = offsetof(tuple,key);
        offsets[1] = offsetof(tuple,index);
        offsets[2] = offsetof(tuple,value);

        // create mpi struct
        MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems,blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_tuples_str);
        MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_tuples_str);

        // Get the number of processes
        int size;
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

        // Get the rank of the process
        int my_rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

        int index = 0;
        int i;
        int local_A_size = (10000%size == 0) ? 10000/size : 0;

        if ( my_rank == 0){
          char text[10000];
          char *p;
          p=strtok(NULL," ");
          // node0 reads file form hard drive and saves file to struct
          while( fgets(text,10000,fp)!=NULL){
            p = strtok (text," ");
            char *temp[3];
            temp[0]=p;
            A[index].key=temp[0];
            p = strtok (NULL, " ");
            temp[1] = p;
            A[index].index=temp[1];
            p = strtok (NULL, " ");
            temp[2] = p;
            A[index].value=temp[2];
            // printf("%s ",A[index].key);
            // printf("%s ",A[index].index);
            // printf("%s\n",A[index].value);
            index++;
          }
          fclose(fp);
        }

        if ( local_A_size != 0){
          if (my_rank == 0) {
            printf("File saved to memory of process %d!\n",my_rank);
            printf("Process %d sending struct data to others...\n",my_rank);
          }

          // send struct to all processes
          MPI_Scatter(&A,local_A_size,mpi_tuples_str,B,local_A_size,mpi_tuples_str,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
          // MPI_Bcast(&A,index,mpi_tuples_str,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

          for(i=0;i<=local_A_size;i++)
           printf("I'm process %d and my result is: %s\n",my_rank,B[i].key);

          if (my_rank == 0) printf("Data sent from process %d to others...\n",my_rank);
        }
        else
        {
          if (my_rank == 0) printf("Number of processes must be an exact divisor of %d, %d in not %ds divisor\n",index,size,index);
        }
          // free memory used by mpi_tuples_str
          MPI_Type_free(&mpi_tuples_str);
          // Finalize
          MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
```

So the problem here is, as far as I can understand_ the creation and allocation of memory of my struct at first and the packing and sending of it at second.
As you can see I've tried both `MPI_Scatter` & `MPI_Bcast` but none of them helped me.
The result is that, as it supposed to, process 0 that reads the file has data but all others not. Also I'm getting this weird message of

```
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
```

I'll be so grateful if someone can enlighten me!!

Alright I 've changed my code to the following:

```
`#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h> // used for offsetof
typedef struct tuple_str{
    char key[10];
    char index[12];
    char value[52];
} tuple;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Initialize file pointer
    FILE *fp = fopen("tuples_mini","r");

    // define original structure that stores file and temp used by each process
    tuple A[10000],B[10000];
    // mpi structure name
    MPI_Datatype mpi_tuples_str;
    // number of structure members
    const int nitems = 3;
    // array of structure member sizes
    int blocklengths[3];
    blocklengths[0] = sizeof(10);
    blocklengths[1] = sizeof(12);
    blocklengths[2] = sizeof(52);
    // structure member types
    MPI_Datatype types[3] = {MPI_CHAR,MPI_CHAR,MPI_CHAR};
    // status
    MPI_Status status;
    // offset of structure members
    MPI_Aint offsets[3];
    offsets[0] = offsetof(tuple,key);
    offsets[1] = offsetof(tuple,index);
    offsets[2] = offsetof(tuple,value);

    // create mpi struct
    MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems,blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_tuples_str);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_tuples_str);

    // Get the number of processes
    int size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int my_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    int index = 0;
    int i;
    int local_A_size = (10000%size == 0) ? 10000/size : 0;
    char *tmp[10000],*b[10000];

    if ( my_rank == 0){
      char text[10000];
      char *p;
      p=strtok(NULL," ");
      // node0 reads file form hard drive and saves file to struct
      while( fgets(text,10000,fp)!=NULL){
        p = strtok (text," ");
        char *temp[3];
        temp[0]=p;
        strcpy(A[index].key,temp[0]);
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        temp[1] = p;
        strcpy(A[index].index,temp[1]);
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        temp[2] = p;
        strcpy(A[index].value,temp[2]);
        printf("%s ",A[index].key);
        printf("%s ",A[index].index);
        printf("%s\n",A[index].value);
        index++;
      }
      fclose(fp);
    }

    if ( local_A_size != 0){
      if (my_rank == 0) {
        printf("File saved to memory of process %d!\n",my_rank);
        printf("Process %d sending struct data to others...\n",my_rank);
      }

      // send struct to all processes
      MPI_Scatter(&A,index,mpi_tuples_str,B,index,mpi_tuples_str,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      // MPI_Bcast(&tmp,index,MPI_CHAR,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      for(i=0;i<=local_A_size;i++){
          // MPI_Recv(&tmp,index,MPI_CHAR,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
          printf("I'm process %d and my result is: %s\n",my_rank,B[i].key);
      }

      if (my_rank == 0) printf("Data sent from process %d to others...\n",my_rank);
    }
    else
    {
      if (my_rank == 0) printf("Number of processes must be an exact divisor of %d, %d in not %ds divisor\n",index,size,index);
    }
      // free memory used by mpi_tuples_str
      MPI_Type_free(&mpi_tuples_str);
      // Finalize
      MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}`
```

but that lead me to new error:

```
    ==============================================================================    =====
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 6
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
==============================================================================    =====
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Aborted (signal 6)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

after last suggestions!

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h> // used for offsetof
typedef struct tuple_str{
    char key[10];
    char index[12];
    char value[52];
} tuple;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Initialize the MPI environment
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  // Initialize file pointer
  FILE *fp = fopen("tuples_mini","r");

  // define original structure that stores file and temp used by each process
 tuple A[10000],B[10000];
 // mpi structure name
 MPI_Datatype mpi_tuples_str;
 // number of structure members
 const int nitems = 3;
 // array of structure member sizes
 int blocklengths[3];
 blocklengths[0] = 11;
 blocklengths[1] = 33;
 blocklengths[2] = 53;
 // structure member types
 MPI_Datatype types[3] = {MPI_CHAR,MPI_CHAR,MPI_CHAR};
 // status
 MPI_Status status;
 // offset of structure members
 MPI_Aint offsets[3];
 offsets[0] = offsetof(tuple,key);
 offsets[1] = offsetof(tuple,index);
 offsets[2] = offsetof(tuple,value);

 // create mpi struct
 MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems,blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_tuples_str);
 MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_tuples_str);

 // Get the number of processes
 int size;
 MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

// Get the rank of the process
int my_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

int index = 0;
int i;
int local_A_size = (10000%size == 0) ? 10000/size : 0;
char *tmp[10000],*b[10000];

if ( my_rank == 0){
  char text[10000];
  char *p;
  // p=strtok(NULL," ");
  // node0 reads file form hard drive and saves file to struct
  while( fgets(text,10000,fp) != NULL && fp != NULL){
    p = strtok (text," ");
    char *temp[3];
    temp[0]=p;
    strcpy(A[index].key,temp[0]);
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
    temp[1] = p;
    strcpy(A[index].index,temp[1]);
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
    temp[2] = p;
    strcpy(A[index].value,temp[2]);
    printf("%s ",A[index].key);
    printf("%s ",A[index].index);
    printf("%s\n",A[index].value);
    tmp[index] = temp[0];
    // printf("%s\n",tmp[index]);
    index++;
  }
  fclose(fp);
}

if ( local_A_size != 0){
  if (my_rank == 0) {
    printf("File saved to memory of process %d!\n",my_rank);
    printf("Process %d sending struct data to others...\n",my_rank);
    // MPI_Send(&A,index,mpi_tuples_str,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  // send struct to all processes
     MPI_Scatter(&A,index,mpi_tuples_str,B,index,mpi_tuples_str,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  // MPI_Bcast(&tmp,index,MPI_CHAR,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  // MPI_Bcast(&A,index,mpi_tuples_str,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  for(i=0;i<=local_A_size;i++){
      // MPI_Recv(&tmp,index,MPI_CHAR,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
      // MPI_Recv(&A,index,mpi_tuples_str,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
      printf("I'm process %d and my result is: %s\n",my_rank,B[i].key);
  }

  if (my_rank == 0) printf("Data sent from process %d to others...\n",my_rank);
}
else
{
  if (my_rank == 0) printf("Number of processes must be an exact divisor of %d, %d in not %ds divisor\n",index,size,index);
}
  // free memory used by mpi_tuples_str
  MPI_Type_free(&mpi_tuples_str);
  // Finalize
  MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof (A->key)` and so on do not return the the maximum length of the string which is required in the call of `MPI_Type_create_struct`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520560(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: ok I won't disagree but how can I get the size of those pointers of arrays of chars?

Comment: I think, you should use fixed sized arrays for `key`, `index` and `value` in your struct. Of course, than you have to use `strcnpy` in your tokenization and also check the string length.

Comment: I guess the `blocklengths[0] = sizeof(10);` should read `blocklengths[0] = 10;` and same goes for the 2 following lines.

Comment: when calling the function: `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `p=strtok(NULL," ");  // node0 reads file form hard drive and saves file to struct` does nothing as the value of `p` is overlayed within the first line of the following loop. and since the function `strtok()` is not previously called with the address of some local buffer, it could be trying to extract a token from anywhere.   This is a good way to cause a seg fault event.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans,  1) consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace '{".  Un-indent before every closing brace '};,  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a single blank line  3) use meaningful variable names.  names like `A` `B`, etc are meaningless. 4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling the function: fopen(), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   Otherwise, trying to read from the file will result in a seg fault event

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using #define statements or an enum to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names and using those meaningful names throughout the code.  Some of the 'magic' numbers are: 10000, 3, 10, 12, 52,

Comment: the calls to `strcpy()` are not limited in length, and require the actual fields to be 9, 11, and 51 character in length, to allow for the trailing NUL byte. However, the posted example input line has fields of 10+1, 32+1, and 52+1!! So the fields in the struct tuple_str array is being repeatedly trashed.  Suggest changing the field lengths to 11, 33, 53

Comment: the posted code is placing some huge data members on the stack.  Strongly suggest allocating those members via `malloc()` (be sure to always check the returned value) and `free()` those areas at the end of the `main()` function

Comment: in the second version of the posted code, the parameters `argc` and `argv[]` are not used.  This causes the compiler to raise to warning messages.  Suggest changing the signature of the `main()` function to: `int main( void )`

Comment: Gilles thx for the comment I forgot to remove sizeof!
@user3629249 thank you too for the comments and th guidance. 
Above I 've posted some changes I've made. Still (with the first strtok commented) I'm getting error code 6. Strange thing I 'll keep getting same error code even if I uncommented. I really am into that I 'm destroying my stack but I thought that MPI_Type_free is doing some cleaning!!

Comment: @user3629249 about your last comment but I 'm having argc, argv for future usage also even if I remove them and place void instead I 'm having the same probs. After all all those errors/warnings are not raising by compiler (mpicc) but at runtime (mpich)!

Comment: what errors/warnings?   the code I posted, compiled with `gcc` with `-c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu99 -ggdb -I/usr/include/mpi mycode.c -o mycode.o`   is not producing any warnings. Please post the errors/warnings you are getting.

Comment: first of all i'm compiling using mpicc mycode.c -o mucode,o and I didn't get any warnings/errors either problem was after invoking mpirun -np 2 ./mycode in order to run application on 2 nodes

Comment: on my computer, with a multi core CPU, this line: `MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);` is setting `size` to be 1, rather than the number of actual cores (4)

Comment: i can't paste the runtime errors form console because of their size but as I said on my previous comment it says (after several I'm process 1 and my result is: ) 
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./mycode terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7338f)[0x7fefa143938f]
.......(more as above)
= Memory map:=
00400000-00402000...(more below)
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 6
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Aborted (signal 6)

Comment: running the program using npirun -np 4 ./mycode did not crash.  However, it did recognize the number of CPUs correctly.  But it did not output the final 3 lines (as posted in my answer

Comment: the `buffer overflow detected` strongly indicates that some line in the input file is not formatted correctly.

Comment: OK i see but size = 1 means (excuse if I 'm making a mistake) only one processes-node-thread you name it. I don't want that I want to scatter my data to several precesses-nodes-threads that's the actual point of what I'm trying to do

Comment: as for the file it has the structure I've posted on my question and actually man thousands of lines like that. Neither empty lines nor something else weird (seen by quick look)

Comment: i also tried to compile it using gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu99 -ggdb -I/usr/include/mpi mycode.c

Comment: when I compiled with mpicc and ran with mpirun -np 4, I did get similar aborts as you mention in your question.  that hints the problem is in the parameters to this line: `MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems,blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_tuples_str);` or ` MPI_Type_create_struct (nitems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_tuples_str);` or  ` MPI_Scatter( &A,index, mpi_tuples_str, B, index, mpi_tuples_str, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`  consideirng those lines are being setup before the actual data is set, may be the problem.

Comment: Just right this is what I was talking about. I'm trying to compile it and run via mpich not just gcc. I 'm really sorry for not posting it earlier. I thought that when by referring to MPI (and to mpich later) that was clear.

Comment: @user3629249 as far as I'm concerned the Mpi creation of custom mpi datatype must be preceding its usage and transmission between mpi nodes. Thats why I'm using  MPI_Type_create_struct before using MPI_Scatter

Comment: you might want to read: `http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/mpi/mpi.html`,  especially follow the links at the end of the page to C example programs

Comment: OK sure I'll check it out. Again thanks for your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied all the comments about problems in the posted code, this is the result:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h> // used for offsetof

typedef struct tuple_str
{
    char key[11];
    char index[33];
    char value[53];
} tuple;

int main( void )
{

    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init( NULL, NULL );

    // Initialize file pointer
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    if( NULL == ( fp = fopen( "tuples_mini" ,"r" ) ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen for read of truples_mini failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    // define original structure that stores file and temp used by each process
    tuple A[10000];
    tuple B[10000];

    // mpi structure name
    MPI_Datatype mpi_tuples_str;

    // number of structure members
    const int nitems = 3;

    // array of structure member sizes
    int blocklengths[3];
    blocklengths[0] = 11;
    blocklengths[1] = 33;
    blocklengths[2] = 53;

    // structure member types
    MPI_Datatype types[3] = { MPI_CHAR, MPI_CHAR, MPI_CHAR };

    // status
    //MPI_Status status;

    // offset of structure members
    MPI_Aint offsets[3];
    offsets[0] = offsetof( tuple,key);
    offsets[1] = offsetof( tuple,index);
    offsets[2] = offsetof( tuple,value);

    // create mpi struct
    MPI_Type_create_struct( nitems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_tuples_str);
    MPI_Type_commit( &mpi_tuples_str);

    // Get the number of processes
    int size;
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int my_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    int index = 0;
    int i;
    int local_A_size = (10000%size == 0) ? 10000/size : 0;
    //char *tmp[10000];
    //char *b[10000];

    if ( my_rank == 0)
    {
      char text[10000];
      char *p;
      //p=strtok(NULL," ");

      // node0 reads file from hard drive and saves file to struct
      while( fgets( text, sizeof text, fp ) )
      {
        p = strtok (text," ");
        char *temp[3];
        temp[0]=p;
        strcpy( A[index].key,temp[0]);

        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        temp[1] = p;
        strcpy( A[index].index,temp[1]);

        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        temp[2] = p;
        strcpy( A[index].value,temp[2]);

        printf( "%s ",A[index].key);
        printf( "%s ",A[index].index);
        printf( "%s\n",A[index].value);
        index++;
      }
      fclose(fp);
    }

    if ( local_A_size != 0)
    {
      if (my_rank == 0)
      {
        printf( "File saved to memory of process %d!\n",my_rank);
        printf( "Process %d sending struct data to others...\n",my_rank);
      }

      // send struct to all processes
      MPI_Scatter( &A,index, mpi_tuples_str, B, index, mpi_tuples_str, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD;
      // MPI_Bcast( &tmp,index, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      for(i=0;i<=local_A_size;i++)
      {
          // MPI_Recv( &tmp, index, MPI_CHAR, 0, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
          printf( "I'm process %d and my result is: %s\n", my_rank, B[i].key);
      }

      if (my_rank == 0) 
          printf("Data sent from process %d to others...\n", my_rank);
    }

    else
    {
      if (my_rank == 0) 
          printf( "Number of processes must be an exact divisor of %d, %d in not %ds divisor\n", index, size,index);
    }

    // free memory used by mpi_tuples_str
    MPI_Type_free( &mpi_tuples_str);

    // Finalize
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I setup the tuples_mini file to contain:

```
AsfAGHM5om  00000000000000000000000000000000  0000222200002222000022220000222200002222000000001111
```

when I ran the program on my ubuntu linux 14.04 with 4 core processor, this is the output:

```
AsfAGHM5om 00000000000000000000000000000000 0000222200002222000022220000222200002222000000001111

File saved to memory of process 0!
Process 0 sending struct data to others...
I'm process 0 and my result is: AsfAGHM5om
I'm process 0 and my result is:
```

then several dozens of this line:

```
I'm process 0 and my result is:
```

followed by these lines:

```
I'm process 0 and my result is: 
I'm process 0 and my result is: AsfAGHM5om
Data sent from process 0 to others...
```

so there seems to be a logic problem in the code, but it does not seg fault

Comment: hmmm well i just copy-paste your corrected code and i'm keep having the same (some I'm process 0 and my result is: ) and at the end

 `*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./a.out terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
...
======= Memory map: ========
...
===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 6
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES


btw i'm runing mpich on a dual core processor with 6gb of ram and 64 bits ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I mark it as accepted because the problem was mpich. I switched to openmpi and everything are OK. Code compiled like a charm and runtime errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

on the second version of the posted code

The most likely cause of the `signal 6/sigabort` is because the first call to `strtok()` has NULL as the first parameter rather than the address of a visible buffer.

IMO: that first call to `strtok()` should be completely removed from the program.